# What is the meaning of a # sign in front of a type in a signature (F#)?

Tags: .net, f#

I have seen the following # sign in some libraries and am not sure what its significance is:

```
let Compile (e: #Expr)
```

The `Expr` is referring to FSharp.Quotations.Expr in this case - not sure if that is relevant.

Answer (score 8):

`#Expr` is a shortcut for `'T when 'T :> Expr`, which can be read as

> some type, which we shall call `T` for now, which is compatible with type `Expr`

MSDN has more documentation on [Flexible Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233198.aspx).

See also [What is the purpose of flexible type annotation in F#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14457571/what-is-the-purpose-of-flexible-type-annotation-in-f) here on Stack Overflow.